# Getting the correct regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've tried endlessly to get the correct regular expression working for what I am after without any luck.  Would appreciate some help.

I have a long string of text (it is actually a formula in Gravity forms) that looks similar to this:

```
(({Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):53} + 
{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):55} + 
{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):57}) * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):21} ) + 

(({Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):54} + 
{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):56} + 
{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):58}) * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):22} )
```

What I am ultimately trying to accomplish is getting this formula in a format so that I can work with it on PHP.  My plan is to use the field ID for which I can pull the info I need via the API.

So my first attempt was trying to isolate the field IDs which are the number between : and } (ie: :22}) while retaining the logic of the formula (+,*,-,/,etc).

So ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
({4} * {54} + {4} * {56} + {4} * {58} * {22}) ....
```

If I am able to get to that point, I should be able to achieve what I am after ultimately, but I have not been able to successfully isolate the field IDs in the format I need them.

Comment: What regular expression have you tried? Show us what you've got and we'll take a look.

Comment: I was trying something like this http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8sf check the preg_replace tab,  but it seems to ignore the first match in the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\([^()\d]*\)|({)[^:]+:|\n
```

Try this.See demo.Replace with `$1`.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/20

```
$re = "/\\([^()\\d]*\\)|({)[^:]+:|\\n/s";
$str = "(({Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):53} + \n{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):55} + \n{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):57}) * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):21} ) + \n\n(({Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):54} + \n{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):56} + \n{Name of Field:4} * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):58}) * {Name of Field (with some more info and numbers):22} )";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not seem to work.  There is no output from using the code you have provided.

Comment: I copy / pasted your code and tried to echo / print_r $matches.  There is no output.  I didn't change anything from your code, it just does not work.

Comment: Another issue is that as per the demo, you are matching just the numbers, I need the actual formula along with the numbers, otherwise I can't really do anything.

Comment: Not sure what changed but i did get the output now,  however i lose my formula operations and logic with your solution.

Comment: @JoseRLopez try now.Check the demo as well.

Comment: Quick bonus question if you do not mind, I noticed that you are adding { through $1, it is otherwise not there.  So just to help me better understand the regular expression, lets say I wanted to remove or replace both {} with something else (maybe a variable name).  So assume I would want to end up with: ($input[4] * $input[53] + $input[4] .... )

Comment: @JoseRLopez yes slight modification would be needed :)